# Can't Open Display - X11 Forwarding - Cent OS

Tags: centos, x11, x11forwarding

Trying to access `X11` my CentOS 6 x32 small Linode VPS through SSH Putty/Xming (enabled X11 forwarding on options).

My windows machine is not the problem since it works with others CentOS Servers.

X11Forwarding is enabled on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, still I can't get X11 forwarding.

I'm trying to get `xclock` to work, but I get `Can't open display :0.0` error.

I've also tried with different $DISPLAY values like `:0` or `:10.0`

I've tried MobaXterm, and I get this message when connecting:

```
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: What X server did you install on your Windows machine?

Comment: Not sure what the CentOS equivalent is, but have you install the xbase-clients?  This should include xauth, and a few other required libraries?

Comment: I did `yum install xclock`, installed lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Here](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/techbriefs/accessing-remote-linux-server-graphical-applications-your-desktop) (Red Hat Login required) is a Tech Brief article from a fellow Red Hat consultant which discusses the minimum packages needed for X-Windows to work for SSH connections.

The key points are:

```
1) Install the following:
xorg-x11-xauth
xorg-x11-fonts-*
xorg-x11-utils
2) Enable the following in the sshd_config file
X11Forwarding yes
3) Use an appropriate X-Server on your desktop
```

Comment: You save me days!!!

Answer (score 8):

Installed this package: 
`xorg-x11-xauth`

Got solution from [here](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=2391).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The bug report was helpfull !
The solution for me was to change the _sshd_config_ to read 
`AddressFamily inet`

as I had deactivated ipv6 via sysctl...